# How to pass huge data by a SQL query between pages (views); any key value pair type of data for passing data instead of index?

Tags: php, sql

I have a form with lots of fields where users are supposed to fill their data and from the admin view, admin can see the form with filled data. So I'm passing data between user view and admin view by a SQL query and in a not professional way I am extracting data by something like below:

```
    $query = "SELECT FName,LName,.... (My Query here)"
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(':flag', $flag, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
```

and then I'm fetching data like below:

```
           $result[0],... $result[55]
```

I know my approach is not professional, what is the better way to fetch data by a name instead of index which is very confusing to figure out what $result[22] is or....

If you give me a simple example it is perfect! Also if my question is not clear please kindly let me know which part you need more clarification! Thanks

Comment: You need to ask specific questions, not just "a better way".

Comment: Sorry about that! But I have no idea what the title can be, could you please suggest me a better title,... Thanks

Comment: The title isn't the problem, the question is. It's not clear what you're asking. Are you having a problem with your program? If so, what is it doing wrong?

Comment: how about table and column names

Comment: @bew Sorry I didn't understand what exactly you mean!

Comment: @ Barmar No my code is working! The problem is that my approach is not professional to pass huge data! and it is too confusing to figure out what index of result I need to use to fetch a specific data; I would like to know what is the better approach to fetch this huge data by names instead of index (which is confusing)

Comment: I'm looking for something like a key, value pair type of data!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

foreach($db->query($sql) as $row)
  echo $row['column1'], $row['column2'], $row['column3'], $row['column4'], "\n";
```

Where `column*` is the name of the column

REVISIED:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somedb', 'username', 'password');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '25' LIMIT 1");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

Both methods return an associative array.

I personally wouldn't bind 55 params, that's why I'm suggesting to use an associative array

Comment: Thanks! No my query is something like $sql = "SELECT FName,LName,... FROM table where id=25; and now for example _age_ is the 25th item of my select query and in order to get _age_ I'm using $result[24] (since it index starts from 0), so it is kind of confusing to figure out the right index...

Comment: Sorry I could not reply to you in comments, maybe because I'm adding some codes and codes probably are not aloowed in comments!Anyway I replied to you in a new reply